# How to include dependencies in the packaged apk?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I refactored my project and removed some external libraries which where in the /app/libs folder of my project. Now I added these libraries in the dependencies section of the gradle build file.

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4.1'
compile ('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.6.9'){
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
```

}

The project can be build and no errors are shown in android studio, but on the device there occur noclassdeffound exceptions. My conclusion is that those jars are not available in the apk file. I could see in the gradle documentation that there is a runtime option which i tried instead of the compile option but this did not work because runtime is not known by the parser. What is the correct way to include these dependencies in the resulting apk file?

My proguard configuration is

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

both files are empty, so I gues that the default will be used
Thanks

Comment: Are you using proguard? Can you paste the stacktrace? Thanks

Comment: Usually,  NoClassDefFound errors are associated with a bad proguard configuration. That is, if proguard is enabled (look for minifyEnabled/shrinkResources in build.gradle) and misconfigured, it might remove some of your external dependencies.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I added my proguard configuration in my post

Comment: It would be useful to see the contents of `proguard-rules.pro` and/or `proguard-android.txt`

Comment: It's a long shot but you can try deleting `C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\.AndroidStudioPreview1.2\system\caches` or `C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\.AndroidStudio\system\caches` depending on the version of Android Studio being used. AS seem to be more buggy than usual atm.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace for the error.  It would be helpful to see specifically which class is not found.